# How can I set the vertical alignment while using 'ul' and 'li'?

Tags: html, css

How can I set the vertical alignment while using 'ul' and 'li'?

Here every font are the same height and same width, so it's hard to explain.
Please see the table below.
Now there is a table about tag cloud.

The tags are actually different sized and the bottom alignment of 'tags:' in  is the same alignment as the top of the largest sized tags.

I want the opposite. the bottom alignment of the largest tags should be the same as the bottom alignment of `tags:` in .

Is it possible?

**Output table**

```
th    td

tags: Apple Banana Strawberry Melon Orange Mango 
      Kiwi Pineapple grapefruit
```

UPDATE:

I made DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/vrqe5/

Please take a look at that.

I want to set the bottom alignment the same.
I mean the bottom aligngment of character `tags:` and very 1st line of li tags words.

Comment: Since all fonts look the same here, why not put together a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) illustrating your problem? A jsFiddle often helps the people answering your question to provide you a quicker answer.

Comment: @thirdender sorry about that I made DEMO. Please check the bottom of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure about your code, but you can try...

```
.yourTagClass{
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-alignment: bottom; //or text-bottom
 }
```

As per your demo, try these styles

```
 div.weekly_tag tr{
    display:table-row;
    vertical-align:text-bottom;
 }

 div.weekly_tag th.tag_title{
    width:90px;
 }

 div.weekly_tag th.tag_tags{
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align:left;
 }

 div.weekly_tag li{
    display:inline;
    white-space:nowrap;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that but it didn't work on mine. I made DEMO. Please check the bottom of my question

Comment: Your demo shows all tags to be bottom vertical aligned. isn't this what you watned.?

Comment: Doesn't it look like the top alignment of characters in both <th> and <li> are the same?

Comment: understood the problem now, have updated answer. Please check.